# Serializer.data gives old values, new ones visible in serializer in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I wrote a custom perform_update(self, serializer) function in a ViewSet but I am having trouble updating the data.
In the code below I see the data={} dictionary containing the old values (that are already in the DB) while the second print shows the data as it was posted. Can anyone please explain how I can use the updated data and why the old data shows up with serializer.data? (See the difference between 'source' and 'verwerking' values in the two prints)

```
class RegisterlineViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Registerline.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RegisterlineSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
...

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        print(serializer.data)
        print(serializer)
```

Result:

```
{'id': 4, 'external_reference': OrderedDict([('source', '7777777'), ('sourcekey', '77777'), ('last_updated', None)]), 'verwerking': '', 'applicatienaam': ...
RegisterlineSerializer(<Registerline: @ [4]>, context={'request': <rest_framework.request.Request: PATCH '/api/registerline/4/'>, 'format': None, 'view': <core.views.RegisterlineViewSet object>}, data={'id': 4, 'external_reference': {'source': '7777gfhngtn777', 'sourcekey': '77777', 'last_updated': None}, 'verwerking': 'gnyghnj',...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `perform_update()` is just called by `update()` which performs the validation via `serializer.is_valid()`. During such validation, the updated values would appear in the `serializer.validated_data` as [documented](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#deserializing-objects), which is the one that you should be accessing.

The `serializer.data` must only be accessed once the instance has been saved/updated already via `serializer.save()`. Only then will you be able to view the updated value in `serializer.data`.